# Is it possible to add controls to the Existing reading pane in the Outlook?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I know a lot of ways how to extend Outlook and add new Reading Panes and Inspectors to the Outlook, but what really bugs me is how to extend and modify the existing reading panes?

I'd like to add more information on these panes without recreating them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this will work for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492010%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226713%28v=office.12%29.aspx

There are other ways to do this, but this seems to be a pretty good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a form region with custom controls to the Reading Pane.

regards,

yenkay